# How to change a Tenant name in WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0?

Tags: server, wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

How is it possible to change a Tenant's name in WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 ?

Is there a way of doing it by changing some DB data or configuration data ?

I changed the

```
<UserName>admin@dcpp103.acn</UserName>
```

in the um_tenant DB Table of the IS Schema and restarted IS but i still see the original Tenant name in the View Tenant section of the UI.

I managed to did this once but now i can't figure it out anymore.

Can you please help out or describe an "official" way of doing it ?

Thank you very much,
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

When you have create a tenant you can't alter the name.  You can only change the admin username, password and email only.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the `<UserName>admin@dcpp103.acn</UserName>` tag content in the `um_tenant` DB Table of the IS Schema.

A Tenant has the following properties:

Tenant Admin:

- First Name*
- Last Name*
- Admin Username

What i needed to change was the Admin Username which cannot be done from the GUI and nobody provided another way of doing it.

It can be done as i already described but it is also needed to restart the WSO2 IS and clear the browser cache to properly apply the change.